# simple Lie algebra as vector spaces $\mathfrak {g}$: contraints on rings or ideals or vector spaces?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, terminology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

A [simple Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_algebra) is a Lie algebra that is nonabelian and contains no nonzero proper ideals.

But the [ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)) are the subset of rings that form a closed structure --- under the left or right multiplication of the full ring on the ideals to be closed. Thus [ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)) are also rings.

However, [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) is a vector space $\mathfrak {g}$ together with an operation called the Lie bracket, an alternating bilinear map together with this operation is a non-associative algebra

Together with an operation called the Lie bracket, an alternating bilinear map ${\mathfrak {g}} \times {\mathfrak {g}} \rightarrow$
$\mathfrak{g}$,  while
$(x,y)\mapsto [x,y]$, that satisfies the Jacobi identity. The vector space ${\mathfrak {g}}$ together with this Lie bracket is a non-associative algebra.

Question 1: So if the Lie algebra is a vector space (a vector space over a field F is a set V together with two operations that satisfy [the eight axioms listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition), which contains a stronger condition on the "fields" more than "rings" (or ideals of the rings), how can the definition of the simple Lie algebra involves a check on the "weaker" ideal property instead of the "stronger" field property?

Question 2:  Both su(2) = so(3) are isomorphic as the same simple Lie algebra.  A simple Lie group is a connected Lie group whose Lie algebra is simple. So SU(2) and SO(3) are two different simple Lie groups and connected Lie group? whose Lie algebra is EXACTLY simple and the same one, because su(2) = so(3)?

Comment: This part may be relevant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Alternative_formulations_and_elementary_consequences

In the parlance of abstract algebra, the first four axioms are equivalent to requiring the set of vectors to be an abelian group under addition. The remaining axioms give this group an F-module structure. In other words, there is a ring homomorphism f from the field F into the endomorphism ring of the group of vectors. Then scalar multiplication av is defined as (f(a))(v).

Comment: The main point of confusion here seems to be the fact that the term "ideal" is used both for Lie algebras and for rings.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's some confusion as to where these ideals live. $\mathfrak{g}$ is a vector space over a field and there are various vector space axioms describing the addition in $\mathfrak{g}$ and the scalar multiplication from the field and how those interact. On top of that we have the structure of an algebra on $\mathfrak{g}$. In other words $\mathfrak{g}$ has a multiplication operation (which we'll denote with brackets) which interacts nicely with the addition and scalar multiplication from earlier. Explicitly:
$$ [X + Y,Z] = [X,Z] + [Y,Z], $$
$$ [X,Y + Z] = [X,Y] + [X,Z], $$
$$\lambda[X,Y] = [\lambda X,Y] = [X,\lambda Y],$$

for all $X, Y, Z \in \mathfrak{g}$ and $\mu, \lambda \in \mathbb{F}$. Saying the same thing another way $[\cdot,\cdot]:\mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ is bilinear. It is a Lie algebra so we also require $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is alternating and satisfies the Jacobi equality. When we talk about simple Lie algebras, the ideals mentioned are ideals of $\mathfrak{g}$ with respect to this bracket operation not ideals of the field (which of course has no non-trivial, proper ideals). An ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$ is a subspace $\mathfrak{i} \leq \mathfrak{g}$ such that $[\mathfrak{i} , \mathfrak{g}] \subset \mathfrak{i}$.

Here are some examples of what an ideal in a Lie algebra looks like.

Let $\mathfrak{t}$ denote the set of upper-triangular matrices with Lie bracket given by the commutator $[A,B] = AB -BA$. Let $\mathfrak{u}$ be the subspace of **strictly** upper-triangular matrices. That is, where the entries on the diagonal are all $0$. Then $\mathfrak{u}$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak{t}$. Indeed, it is the biggest proper ideal although there are some obvious smaller ones if you play around a bit.

Another simple example comes whenever we make the direct sum of Lie algebras. That is we have Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}_1$, $\mathfrak{g}_2$ and we set $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{g}_1 \oplus \mathfrak{g}_2$ (a direct sum of vector spaces) such that the bracket of any element of $\mathfrak{g}_1$ with one from $\mathfrak{g}_2$ is $0$. Then $\mathfrak{g}_1$, $\mathfrak{g}_2$ are both ideals of $\mathfrak{g}$.

As to your second question, yes. Those are two non-isomorphic simple Lie groups but whose Lie algebras are isomorphic. Indeed $SU(2)$ is a double cover of $SO(3)$. They are however "locally isomorphic" which is why they have the same Lie algebra.

Comment: But the result here is most definitely not a ring, since part of being a ring is the requirement of the product being associative (and this seems to be part of the confusion from the OP).

Comment: Ah, good point. It is indeed not a ring although we can still talk about ideals in the same fashion. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: To make this good answer (already upvoted) perfect, maybe include some trivial and some non-trivial examples of ideals and non-ideals. (Although this is the fun part that a beginner should actually figure out by playing around for oneself.)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Good idea! I'll put some in.